# Find a specific file in an archive using PHP

Tags: php, recursion, zip, archive

I have an archive (zipped) file. A user archives it so there is no standard that is being followed. This file has several folders and files in it. But I am only interested in one file '**FOI.zip**'. FOI.zip is an archive within a zip file.

Eg: Main file is what I have and needs to be searched..
Possible Structures within Main.zip

```
1.
/Main.zip
 /A
  /FOI.zip
 /B
 /C

2.
/Main.zip
 /A
  /a.zip
   /FOI.zip
 /B
 /C
3.
/Main.zip
 /XYZ
  /A
   /FOI.zip
  /B
  /C
```

In PHP I would like to search for FOI.zip recursively and get the path for FOI.zip.
I greatly appreciate any help.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understood it well, you need to find a FOI.zip in the archive, is it right?

If yes, you have this sollution:

```
<?php 
system('unzip' . $zip file);
system('find . | grep FOI.zip', $relative_path);

// $relative_path is a where FOI.zip is, if it's empty - means no FOI.zip found.
?>
```

Comment: archive could have another archive in it. so FOI.zip could be in A.zip and A.zip in Main.zip?

Comment: When you didn't find anything, you can to unzip all the zip archives you have in the previous zip archive. You will find them with the GREP as well..